# Design C++ method that accepts variable number arguments passed from QtScript

Tags: c++, qt, qtscript

I am learning QtScript and wrote several trivial examples. The mapping is straightforward if I limit arguments to simple types.

I now want to be able to pass variable number of arguments from QtScript to the C++ class, such as

```
Myobject.add(1, 2, 3, "4444");
Myobject.add( {first:1, second:2, third:333} );
```

How to declare the method in the C++ implement?

Answer (score 1):

A quick search suggests you use `QVariantList`:

```
void Myobject::add(QVariantList& l)
{
    for( QVariantList::const_iterator i(l.begin()); i != l.end(); ++i ) {
        QVariant elem(*i);
        if( elem.canConvert<QVariantMap>() ) {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

I don't have the tools to test this right now though.

Comment: This would add an overload for calls with one array argument while the OP seems to look for a way to pass a variable number of arguments to one function (for which it looks like there is no convenience support?).